# Calling a object function in Angular 2 from template throws ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self.context.$implicit.myFunction is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a `Mail` model object:

```
export class Mail {
  id: string;
  tags: Array<String>;
  subject: string;

  constructor(data: any = {}) {
    this.id = data.id || null;
    this.subject = data.subject || null;
    this.tags = data.tags || null;
  }

  private indexOfFlagged() {
    return this.tags.indexOf('flagged');
  }

  public isEmpty(): boolean {
    return this.id == null;
  }

  public isStarred(): boolean {
    return this.indexOfFlagged() != -1
  }
}
```

and the following template:

```
<div *ngIf="!mail.isEmpty()">
  <h3>{{ mail.subject }}</h3>

  <div>
    <a class="fa" [class.fa-star-o]="!mail.isStarred()" [class.fa-star]="mail.isStarred()" click="toggleStar($event)"></a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <!-- body here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The `isStarred()` function could not be invoked after I update the model via the `(click) event`. The first time the template renders, all works very well and the function could be invoked. Could anybody tell me why this happens here?

All I get is this error in the console: `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self.context.$implicit.isStarred is not a function`. The problem is: when I use a property instead of the function it works well.

I'm using **angular-rc3**.

Comment: What does that click event do? Perhaps it is breaking something